# retrieve checkbox values from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing checkbox values in a intermediate table in a one-to-many pattern. for updating the checkbox values how to populate the whole list with those checked which are stored on that table.

**item table**

```
+----------+--------------+
| item_id  |   item_name  | 
+-------------+-----------+
| 1        | A            |
| 2        | B            |
| 3        | C            |
| 4        | D            |
| 5        | E            |
+----------+--------------+
```

**item_tag**

```
    +----------+--------------+
    | item_id  |     tag_id   | 
    +-------------+-----------+
    | 1        | 1            |
    | 1        | 2            |
    | 2        | 1            |
    | 2        | 2            |
    | 2        | 3            |
    +----------+--------------+
```

**tag_table**

```
+----------+--------------+
| tag_id   |     tag_name | 
+-------------+-----------+
| 1        | foo          |
| 2        | bar          |
| 3        | foo1         |
| 4        | bar1         |
| 5        | foo2         |
+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your checked values with original checkboxes, with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php
    // get the checked items
    // SELECT * FROM `item_tag` WHERE `item_id` = 2
    $checkedItems = [1, 2, 3];

    // get the checkboxes
    // SELECT * FROM `tag_table`
    $checkboxes = [1=>'foo', 2=>'bar', 3=>'foo1', 4=>'bar1', 5=>'foo2'];
?>


<?php foreach ($checkboxes as $index => $value): ?>
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="<?php echo $index; ?>"

        <?php if (in_array($index, $checkedItems)): ?>
            checked="checked"
        <?php endif; ?>
    />
    <?php echo $value; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: In the first query form item_tag why should I select all instead of just tag_id

Comment: @freaky_coder Because you want to show **all** checkboxes to the user, to allow the user change them.

Comment: retrieved values are not checked.